# How to remove an eroneous system update from the App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I recently ran the 10.14.6 updater on my MacPro and the installer glitched and deleted my admin privileges from my boot drive. The computer still worked, but constantly stalled since it thought I didn't have permission to do almost anything.

I tried several fixes and none of them worked. The solution that did work was to clone my 10.14.6 boot drive from my MacBook Pro. That worked fine, but it came with an annoying thing that I can't get rid of.

During the update process to Mojave I skipped 10.11 El Capitan, but the app store had already downloaded the beginning of that update.

Now, even though the computer is running 10.14.6 it tries to download the 10.11 update, but then realizes it can't and quits, but it never deletes the update file so it repeats every night.

Really annoying. I have tried several searches for the hidden cache file, but I can't find where Apple hid this file that keeps trying to do this.
Does anybody know where this file is so I can delete it?